# Dynamic content mage JS Translation

Tags: magento2, js-translation

So first and foremost excuse me if this has been asked before, but there are so many questions regarding not working js translations that I didnt find any matching mine.

I had an issue where I wanted to dynamically translate the result of an API undercertain circumstances in JS like this:

```
value['availability'] = $.mage.__(value['availability']);
```

But no matter what I did the value wouldnt be translated, while it would if I used the static text instead of variable aka:

```
value['availability'] = $.mage.__('Ask Us');
```

After a bit of debugging I came to this situation:

```
// $.mage.__('Ask Us');
value['availability'] = $.mage.__(value['availability']);
```

Which then magically worked, so I came to the following conclusion, something in the generation of js-translation.json seems to check wether or not the csv translations actually appear in js files.

After a bit more grumbling I came to the thought that possibly this is the case to prevent a huge file beeing loaded client side everytime a user opens the page, so actually expected behaviour.

But now is the issue if thats expected behaviour, whats the expected solution for dynamic translations, because I dont think its to rare that someone wants to translate the returns of an AJAX call, for example translating error msgs.

But putting every possibilty of a dynamic translation in a comment above is probably not the intended way to go, so I was wondering what is?

Comment: Have you able to translate dynamic value coming from ajax call ?

Comment: @クジェー if u are calling something with AJAX within magento context you would probably be fine to use the normal __() within PHP. 

If its outside of it, and the result is within a predictable range of options u can use the hack i described above. Where u put the possible strings in a comment so they get added into the translation js

Comment: I already found the caused. It seems it does not translate text coming from an API result. I think it only translate text that already exist/hard coded on the file.